# How to get rid of Sonata's "orphan containers"?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working on a project that uses Sonata's page bundle and block bundle. The relevant part of my sonata_page.yml file looks like this:

```
templates:
    default:
        path: 'AppBundle:Layout:app_default.html.twig'
        name: 'default'
        containers:
            header:
                name: Header
            content_top:
                name: Top content
            content:
                name: Main content
            content_bottom:
                name: Bottom content
            footer:
                name: Footer
        matrix:
            layout: |

                HHHHHHHH
                TTTTTTTT
                TTTTTTTT
                CCCCCCCC
                CCCCCCCC
                BBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBB
                FFFFFFFF

            mapping:
              H: header
              T: content_top
              C: content
              B: content_bottom
              F: footer
    index:
        path: 'MyNewBundle:Default:index.html.twig'
        name: 'index'
        containers:
            content:
                name: Main content
        matrix:
            layout: |
                CCCCCCCC

            mapping:
              C: content
```

This works pretty well. When I choose "index" as the template for a page, I find that the "compose" tab for that page contains only one option: Main Content.

The problem is that I still see an "orphan containers" area at the bottom of the page, allowing the user to select Header, Top content, Bottom content and Footer. **I want to remove those "orphan containers" so they don't show up. Is there a simple way to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

I found that dropping the database and re-running `make install` was enough to get rid of the orphan containers.

That's maybe a bit draconian, but it did the trick.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you explain more on how you fixed this?